# The way to stack files in obspy

Tags: python, stack, obspy

I got 10 data files which have 24 traces (MASW results).

I need to stack 10 data files and made the code but the append part in the code to stack.

Could you please edit the append part to stack in the code?

Or if you know the way to stack output files in geopsy program, please let me know.

```
import os
from obspy import read, Stream, Trace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

path='/path/to/folder/'
Jo_list=os.listdir(path)


stack_format='_stack.dat'
usual_format='.dat'
for jo in Jo_list:
    file_list=os.listdir(path+jo)
    real_list=[]
    #The part to extract file list that I need
    for file in file_list:
        if file.endswith(usual_format):
            real_list+=[file]
            if file.endswith(stack_format):
                real_list.remove(file)
                
    print(real_list)
    
    stream = read(path+jo+'/'+real_list[0])
    
    new_stream = Stream()

    # Loop over each trace in the first file
    for i in range(len(stream)):
        # Extract the trace data and header information
        data = stream[i].data
        header = stream[i].stats
        
        # Loop over the remaining files
        for j in range(1, len(real_list)):
            # Read the file into a Stream object
            tmp_stream = read(path+jo+'/'+real_list[j])
            
            # Loop over each trace in the file
            for k in range(len(tmp_stream)):
                # Check if the header information matches
                if tmp_stream[k].stats == header:
                    # Extract the matching trace data and append it to the data from the first trace
                    data += tmp_stream[k].data
                    
        # Create a new Trace object from the combined data and header information and append it to a new Stream object
        new_trace = Trace(data=data, header=header)
        new_stream.append(new_trace)
    
    plt.plot(new_stream)
    plt.title(jo)
    plt.show()
```